Xamarin.iOS System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file AppIcon60x60@2x.png
I just completed my iOS project in VS 2022 v17.9.7 and was finishing up by adding my app icons to the asset catalog.  I was able to successfully add the icons and now I get an error when I attempt to deploy the app to my physical iPhone 13 iOS 17.4.1 with the error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error       System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/Users/prescottchartier/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/OML_iOS/925fc282e7624c296284fb3051c5d4c69f7dc7a0bdbfa5fe84b98a136988d552/obj/iPhone/Debug/actool/bundle/AppIcon60x60@2x.png"
File name: '/Users/prescottchartier/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/OML_iOS/925fc282e7624c296284fb3051c5d4c69f7dc7a0bdbfa5fe84b98a136988d552/obj/iPhone/Debug/actool/bundle/AppIcon60x60@2x.png'
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x00259] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:274 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:106 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare,int,System.IO.FileOptions)
  at System.IO.FileSystem.CopyFile (System.String sourceFullPath, System.String destFullPath, System.Boolean overwrite) [0x00025] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/FileSystem.Unix.cs:54 
  at System.IO.File.Copy (System.String sourceFileName, System.String destFileName, System.Boolean overwrite) [0x00056] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs:74 
  at Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.SmartCopyTaskBase.CopyFile (System.String source, System.String target, System.String targetItemSpec) [0x0002d] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks/Tasks/SmartCopyTaskBase.cs:64 
  at Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.SmartCopyTaskBase.Execute () [0x000a4] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks/Tasks/SmartCopyTaskBase.cs:97 OML_iOS C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets   1163        

I am able to deploy the app to the iPhone iOS 15.5 and iOS 17.4 simulators and the launch icon does display just fine but I did notice that my LaunchScreen.storyboard does not display when the app launches.  I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it, but when I was able to deploy the app the the physical device, the LaunchScreen.storyboard did display.  Nowhere in my app do I reference AppIcon60x60@2x.png, it's not listed in the .csproj file, and a seach of the entire project says that it isn't in the project.  I cleaned the solution, close VS, deleted the bin and obj directories, and reloaded and re-compiled the app.  Same error. I have no idea how to fix this.
I reported the issue to the Microsoft Developer Community, but I believe they dropped support of Xamarin as of May 24th, 2024, so I don't think they're going to assist me.  I'm hoping that someone here knows whats going on and what if any fix or workaround there may be.  This will be my last Xamarin developed app as I will be moving to the MAUI platform, I just need to get this app out there.

Well, turned out to be a simple problem.  It really would be helpful if Microsoft would generate an error message that was more precise to the actual error. AppIcon60x60@2x.png simply doesn't exist, so I was never going to find it.  It turned out that two of of the icon files I was using had a depth of 24 bit and a depth of 32 bit was required.  I used Gimp to add an transparency alpha channel to the icon and that corrected the problem.  If you're using Gimp, load the icon file, right click on the image, select Layer from the menu, select Transparency from the next menu, click Add Alpha Channel.  Export the image and overwrite the file your loaded and then you should have a correct bit depth.
It seems to me that this issue could have been caught easily when I selected the icon file when setting them in the asset catalog, a more concise error message would have saved me a lot of frustration.
